# Made a Priority Queue, having problems with delMin and insert

Tags: java, arraylist, priority-queue

I have made a Priority Queue class with an array list, but I am having trouble with the insert and delMin (delete minimum areas). I cannot create more functions and here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class MyMinPQ<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E> {
    private ArrayList<E> pq;
    private int N;

    public MyMinPQ() {
        pq = new ArrayList<E>();
    }

    public E delMin(){
        E minVal = min();
        pq.remove(0);
        N--;
        return minVal;
    }
    public E min (){
        if (isEmpty()) 
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return pq.get(0);
    }
    public void insert (E item){
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            pq.add(item);
            if (pq.get(i) > pq.get(i+1)) {
                E tmp = pq.get(i);
                pq.set(i+1, tmp);
        }
        }
        N++;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return N == 0;
    }
    public int size() {
        return N;
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<E>(){
            int current = 0;
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return current != size();
            }
            public E next() {
                if (hasNext())
                    return pq.get(current++);
                else throw new NoSuchElementException( ); 
            }
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException( );             
            }   
        };
    }
}
```

At the insert portion of the code, I know that I have to sort the new additions to Arraylist but I am having issues with going about this. I tried to compare the values that is within the list, but eclipse does not allow it based on how I formatted it. When I use compareTo, it does not work with my iterator and everything goes into disarray.

My question is how can I go about modifying my insert function so it can sort new items in descending order? Will my `delMin()` also have to change because of it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void insert(E item) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < N && pq.get(i).compareTo(item) <= 0) {
        i++;
    }
    N++;
}
```

Comment: I also added pq.add(item) above the while statement, but still having issues with a correct output :/ IDK what's wrong. I thought of comparing the values but its something small(I think) that I'm missing